# Custom Boot animation is not working in Android Jelly Bean

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, boot-animation

I am reading [this tutorial for creating a custom boot animation](http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/how-to-change-customize-create-android-boot-animation-guide/).

I have created a custom `bootanimation.zip` and put this file into the `system/media/` folder but it's not working. When I replace it with the original `bootanimation.zip` it works fine.

How can I get my custom boot animation to work?

Comment: I have tried to clean up your post to make it more understandable. Please [edit] it if I misinterpreted what you were saying.

Comment: What device do you have? Reading that link it seems there are limitations on some devices. Also, have you unzipped the original boot animation to see that yours looks similar?

Comment: @MichaelKohne smile tablet  1024*768 resoltion 7 inch.